# Проблемы со шрифтом в PDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

PDF генерируется из HTML c помощью `dompdf` и `snappy`. После некоторых букв как будто стоят пробелы (в коде их нет). Используется шрифт `TimesNewRoman` и свойство `text-align: justify`. Пробовал другой шрифт – проблема остаётся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать для генерации [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) – там не встречали подобных проблем.

Или же, как вариант, уберите `text-align: justify` – возможно из-за него идут разрывы. Вместо этого свойства можно попробовать сделать переносы `hypnes: auto`, чтобы не оставалось на строке много пустого пространства.